# switch between hibernate and jdbc connection

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, arraylist

I am building an app that use both hibernate and jdbc to connect on my database.
At the beginning if the user choose "1" it will call the "chiamaRicercaOfferta" method from RicercatoreJDBC which call a stored procedure on the database
and it works great! 
The main problem is when the user choose "2" because the app should call the same stored prcedure with a hibernate connection in "RicercatoreHibernate" but i've read that is not possible so i'm only trying to show my database but i got this cast error and i don't know how to move anymore!
Can someone help me please?

**The Error Message**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to it.Offerta

**The RicercatoreHibernate class**

```
    package it;


import org.hibernate.Session;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RicercatoreHibernate implements Ricercatore{

    public RicercatoreHibernate() {}

    public boolean connetti() {
        return false;       
    }

    public void disconnetti() {}

    public boolean isConnesso() {
        return false;
    }


    //Operazione di Insert su Database
    public int insertOfferta(int ID_offerta,String nomeAzienda, String titolo, int postiVacanti, String ID_randomOfferta ) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Offerta offerta = new Offerta(ID_offerta, nomeAzienda, titolo, postiVacanti, ID_randomOfferta);

        //int ID_offerta = (Integer)session.save(offerta);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return ID_offerta;
    }

    public ArrayList<Offerta> chiamaRicercaOfferta(String k)throws SQLException{

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<Offerta> lista =session.createSQLQuery("select o.ID_offerta, o.ID_randomOfferta, o.titolo, o.postiVacanti from OffertaLavoro o").list();

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return (ArrayList<Offerta>) lista;
    }



    public List<Offerta> list(){
        Session session =HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<Offerta> result = session.createSQLQuery("select o.ID_offerta, o.ID_randomOfferta, o.titolo, o.postiVacanti from OffertaLavoro o").list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return result;

    } }
```

**Main Class**

```
package it;


import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class OffertissimApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        String k=" ";
        String risposta=" ";
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Offerta> lista =new ArrayList<Offerta>();
        Welcome ciao = new Welcome();

        RicercatoreFactory ricFactory =new RicercatoreFactory();
        Ricercatore ilRicercatore = null;

        System.out.println("Cosa vuoi fare?");
        System.out.println("Digita 1 per effettuare una ricerca con JDBC");
        System.out.println("Digita 2 per effettuare una ricerca con Hibernate");

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String tipoSelezionato = userInput.nextLine();
        ilRicercatore = ricFactory.makeRicercatore(tipoSelezionato);

        if(ilRicercatore == null) {
            System.out.println("Devi selezionare una delle operazioni disponibili");
        }



        System.out.println("Vuoi effettuare una ricerca?");
        System.out.println("Inserisci SI per continuare oppure NO per uscire");

        risposta =in.next();
        while (!(risposta.equals("no"))){
            System.out.println("Inserisci una chiave di ricerca");
            k=in.next();
            lista =ilRicercatore.chiamaRicercaOfferta(k);
            System.out.println("------------------Ecco i risultati!-----------------");

            for (Offerta list:lista){
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("| ID_offerta | Nome Azienda | Titolo Offerta | numero posti vacanti | ID_randomOfferta |");
                System.out.println(list);
                System.out.println(" ");
            }

            System.out.println("Vuoi effettuare una nuova ricerca?");
            System.out.println("Inserisci SI per continuare oppure NO per uscire");
            risposta =in.next();
        }


        System.out.println("Ciao!");
        in.close();
        userInput.close();
    }
}
```

**Offerta POJO class**

```
    package it;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    @javax.persistence.Entity(name = "OffertaLavoro")

    //@Table(name = "OffertaLavoro")
    public class Offerta {       
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
         private int ID_offerta;  
            private String nomeAzienda;
            @Column(name = "titolo", nullable = false)
            private String titolo;
            @Column(name = "postiVacanti", nullable = false)
            private int postiVacanti;
            @Column(name = "ID_randomOfferta", nullable = true)
            private String ID_randomOfferta;
    //      private int fk_IDAzienda_offertaLAvoro;
    //      private Azienda azienda;

/*Costruttori*/ 
            public Offerta() {
            }

        public Offerta(int ID_offerta, String nomeAzienda, String titolo,
                int postiVacanti, String ID_randomOfferta) {
            this.ID_offerta=ID_offerta;
            this.nomeAzienda=nomeAzienda;
            this.titolo=titolo;
            this.postiVacanti=postiVacanti;
            this.ID_randomOfferta=ID_randomOfferta;
        }

        public Offerta(int ID_offerta, String titolo,
                int postiVacanti, String ID_randomOfferta) {
            this.ID_offerta=ID_offerta;
            this.titolo=titolo;
            this.postiVacanti=postiVacanti;
            this.ID_randomOfferta=ID_randomOfferta;
        }

        /**
         * Metodi get
         * 
         */
        @Id
        public int getID_offerta() {
            return this.ID_offerta;
        }

        public String getNomeAzienda() {
            return this.nomeAzienda;
        }

        public String getTitolo() {
            return this.titolo;
        }

        public int getPostiVacanti() {
            return this.postiVacanti;
        }

        public String getID_randomOfferta() {
            return this.ID_randomOfferta;
        }

        /*
        public int getFk_IDAzienda_offertaLAvoro() {
            return this.fk_IDAzienda_offertaLAvoro;
        }
        */


        /**
         * Metodi set
         * 
         */
        public void setID_offerta(int ID_offerta) {
            this.ID_offerta=ID_offerta;
        }


    public void setNomeAzienda(String Azienda) {
            nomeAzienda=Azienda;
        }

        public void setPostiVacanti(int vacanti) {
            postiVacanti=vacanti;
        }

        public void setTitolo(String titolo) {
            this.titolo=titolo;
        }

        public void setID_randomOfferta(String ID_randomOfferta) {
            this.ID_randomOfferta=ID_randomOfferta;
        }

    /*  @ManyToOne
     *  @JoinColumn(name="ID_azienda")
     *  public void setFk_IDAzienda_offertaLAvoro(int fk_IDAzienda_offertaLAvoro) {
     *  this.fk_IDAzienda_offertaLAvoro= fk_IDAzienda_offertaLAvoro;
     *  }
     *  public Azienda getAzienda() {
     *      return azienda;
     *  }
     *  
     *  public void setAzienda(Azienda azienda) {
     *      this.azienda=azienda;
     *  }
     */ 



        //Override di hashCode
            public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ID_offerta;
            return result;
            }


        //Override di equals
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (!(obj instanceof Offerta))
                return false;
            final Offerta offerta =(Offerta) obj;
            if(!offerta.getTitolo().equals(getTitolo()))
                return false;
            return true;
           }


        //Override di toString
        public String toString() {
            return "       "+ ID_offerta +"         "+ nomeAzienda +"      "
                    +titolo +"        "+ postiVacanti +"               "+ ID_randomOfferta;
        }
    }
```

**Hibernate cfg file if can be usefull**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory >
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">pippo</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pippo</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\sqlserver:1433;user=pollo;password=pollo;databaseName=Cosissime</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_entity_mode">pojo</property>
  <mapping class="it.Offerta"/>
  <mapping class="it.Azienda"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**The Stored procedure i would be able to launch**

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[trovaLavoro]

    @temp varchar(50)
    --,@out varchar(50) OUTPUT
as
begin 

    print 'Inserisci titolo annuncio';
    select o.ID_offerta, o.ID_randomOfferta,a.nomeAzienda, o.titolo, o.postiVacanti
    from OffertaLavoro o join Azienda a on o.fk_IDAzienda_offertaLavoro= a.ID_azienda
    where titolo like '%'+@temp+'%' --or titolo like '%%'       

END
```

If is there something else i can provide yoi to arrive to a solution just let me know!
Thanks very much everybody would try to help me!!

**EDIT 1**

I fixed the previuous problem but now it gives me this

> ERROR: Sintassi non corretta in prossimità di '@P0'.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2122)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1905)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2429)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1980)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
>       at it.RicercatoreHibernate.chiamaRicercaOfferta(RicercatoreHibernate.java:45)
>       at it.OffertissimApp.main(OffertissimApp.java:50)
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Sintassi non corretta in prossimità di '@P0'.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:467)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:409)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:219)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:199)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:331)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
>       ... 15 more

I've understood that this problem is related to the hibernate dialect that not support sql server 2017

any tips on how to solve?

Comment: Hibernate is built on top of JDBC.   You're free to create a JDBC connection and call that stored proc without using Hibernate.  What is the question here?

Comment: why in my code there is  a cast error even if i've casted "arraylist" on the ricercatoreHibernate lista?

Comment: That's a simple Java problem, nothing to do with Hibernate or JDBC.  If the class doesn't implement or extend that type you can't cast to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using native sql queries with Hibernate you must use addEntity(Class entityType) method, so that Hibernate could understand what class must be mapped for query result.
It looks like this:

```
session.createSQLQuery("select o.ID_offerta, o.ID_randomOfferta, o.titolo, o.postiVacanti from OffertaLavoro o").addEntity(Offerta.class).list();
```

But, I suggest using HQL or JPQL for such simple queries